# What are the directories and configuration files used to set the umask by the superuser in Solaris UNIX?

Tags: solaris, login, root, umask

One file I can think of is the .profile file in the user's home directory.  However what are the absolute paths (directories and file names) that are used to set the UMASK level at the operating system level by the superuser to apply to all users in Solaris UNIX?

Comment: /etc/profile. But the admin cannot force a user to use an umask -- any user can change it. The umask is inherited by child processes and many programs will set it to 022, just to be sure (eg. ssh). My older solaris systems (fortunately!) don't have anything like pam_umask.

Comment: I've checked two UNIX boxes.  The "umask 022" command is in the "/etc/profile" file of both UNIX boxes.  So putting a "umask" command in the ".profile" file of the user's home directory can override this system wide superuser setting in "/etc/profile"?